# Koa router: How to get query string params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-string, koa, koa-router

I'm using koa-router.

How can I get the request's query string params?

This is the best I managed to write:

```
import koaRouter from 'koa-router';

const router = koaRouter({ prefix: '/courses' });

router.get('/', async (ctx) => {
        console.log(ctx.qs["lecturer"]);
    });
```

but `qs` is undefined

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

According to the docs there should be a `ctx.request.query` that is the query string items represented as an object.

Comment: ctx.request.query is undefined, although ctx.request.url is  '/api/courses?lecturer=John_Smith'

Comment: @Alon how are you mounting the router onto the app?

Comment: I don't know what was changed, but suddenly ctx.request.query is working

Comment: @JosephAstrahan you will need to revisit your edit and comment. That's quite misleading comment and edit there. @Cory Robinson is right. It should simply be `ctx.query` which comes from `koa` where `koa-router` just passes along with the request [as mentioned here](https://koajs.com/#request). Had the OP asked just for "url params" then you'd be right but the question is about "query string" params. Not the same thing.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The correct usage is `ctx.request.query` (or the alias `ctx.query`) at the time of this writing.

Comment: I undid the edit that added incorrect information and code sample.

Comment: How to get url params instead of query?

Answer (score 28):

You can use `ctx.query` (or long-hand `ctx.request.query`)

`app.use( (ctx) => console.log(ctx.query) )`

Comment: Interesting that my WebStorm does not show such property 'ctx.query' at ctx inspecting in debugger, but at direct access it does work.

Comment: @dzenly this is because that's actually a shortcut (getter), the actual path is `ctx.request.query`